# Automatically run VM and attach VSCode for remote develop

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I have a project which closely work with linux kernel and thus development environment is qemu with exact linux kernel version and generic ubuntu rootfs.

There is a script that can launch qemu with some custom kernel, initrd and rootfs, forward SSH port and finally mount folder with source code into system in rootfs over 9p protocol.

Right now developers usually launching dev env using script, then configure remote SSH inside VSCode and connect to this remote over SSH.

Is there any way to "integrate" this process with VSCode interface in a way like it does Dev Containers extension?

Maybe there any VSCode API so custom extension can try to launch current window to the remote VSCode?

Some crazy ideas like creating custom docker context and mocking docker server is also accepted.

Comment: [Tasks](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks) might be worth looking into if you haven't already.

Comment: Tasks will not help me as it just inconvenient way to execute process.